# creating json array from arraylist android

Tags: php, android, json

I've been toying around with this for a little while and I'm looking for some help. I have an `ArrayList` that I turn into a `JSONArray` and then place inside `JSONObject`. The problem is my formatting. Allow me to show you.

I get the values for my `ArrayList` and add them like so (small code snippet)

```
if (v instanceof EditText) {
        String answer = ((EditText) v).getText().toString();
        if (answer.equals("")) {
        error.setText(v.getTag().toString()
            + " Needs an answer");
        ((EditText) v).setHint("Fill me out!");
        ((EditText) v).setHintTextColor(getResources()
            .getColor(R.color.red_bg));
        } else {
            error.setText("");
        }
        String question = v.getTag().toString();
        String combo = question + ": " + answer;
        myList.add(combo);
        Log.v("INFO", "Storing: " + combo);
}
```

This works, but adding the ":" is the start of my problems. The log prints out

```
06-19 12:13:33.630: V/INFO(3272): Storing: Height: 6`4
```

Now when I create my `JSON` to be sent over I use the following

```
if (error.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(myList);
    try {
       json.putOpt("array", jArray);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Again, this works. Now the problem clearly illustrated, it prints out `JSON` like this

```
{
  "array":
  [
    "Store #: 00608",
    "Phone #: null",
    "Address: 3014 N. SCOTTSDALE RD.",
    "City: SCOTTSDALE",
    "Zip: 85251",
    "State: AZ",
    "Height: 6`4",
    "Weight: 230",
    "Ethnicity: White",
    "Age: 23",
    "Eye Color: Blue",
    "Favorite Food: Thai",
    "Comments: awesome"
   ]
}
```

If you're familiar with `JSON` you know I've goofed it here. I was merely trying to keep the question and answer together. However by adding the ":" to the middle it looks like I'm trying to use question as the `key` and answer as the `value` (kind of). Anyways in the end this looks like legitimate `JSON`, and it is, but it doesn't work the way I need it to.

**My question is, should I just make "question" the `key`, and "answer" the `value`?**

If so how would I go about creating my `JSONArray` so that my `JSON` looks like this

```
{
  "array":
  [
    "Store #" :  "00608",
    "Phone #" : "null",
    "Address" : "3014 N. SCOTTSDALE RD.",
    "City" : "SCOTTSDALE",
    "Zip" : "85251",
    "State" : "AZ",
    "Height" : "6`4",
    "Weight" : "230",
    ....
   ]
}
```

So that a simple

```
var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

in `PHP` will provide me with the data I need server side.

**or alternatively** would it just be simpler to keep this format and split the strings as I parse them server side? Whichever answer you choose please supply a few lines of code with to illustrate your answer. As you can tell I'm a visual person.

Thanks for the help, I hope this helps other people in the future as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this a bunch of ways. If you want to keep the formatting the way it is you just need to process your strings first. When you get values from your `ArrayList` just split the combo into parts

```
int splitPoint = combo.indexOf(":")
String key = combo.substring(0, splitPoint);
String value = combo.substring(splitPoint + 1);
```

Once you split the key and value out just create a new `JSONObject` and add the key and value as a string

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
jObject.put(key, value);
```

This will add the JSONString to its own JSONObject. Then you can add this object to the JSONArray that you want to create

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
jArray.puJSONObject(jObject);
```

I broke this down in to parts but if you just decalre your `JSONArray` ouside a for loop or some other iterator and loop through your `ArrayList`, processing each combo string and adding the resulting object to a `JSONArray` you can acheive the desired result

Comment: I think this is the most complete answer so I am accepting it. I have decided to keep the format and split up the strings server side. I will simply run a for loop through an array and place the values where I need them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that you can do the following in JSON

```
[ "key":"value, ...."].
```

You may be able to do it with Key Value object pairs, as in

```
[ {"key":"value"},...]
```

If you do it with objects, you will have to create a new object for each pair, and it might become pretty complicated since the key in JSON corresponds with the name of an instance variable.

My suggestion is to leave it the way you have it now and split the strings. I am not familiar with PHP, but it should be as simple as looping through the JSON array and calling something like split(':') on the strings.

Comment: You're correct and that is how I would need to do this. I would have to put question and answer for each into its own object and then stuff that in an array and then stuff that in an object and ... ya. Complicated. Much easier to just take it the way I have it and split it up server side

Answer (score 1):

You can make a JSONObject with dynamic keys like so:

```
{
    "Store #" :  "00608",
    "Phone #" : "null",
    "Address" : "3014 N. SCOTTSDALE RD.",
    "City" : "SCOTTSDALE",
    "Zip" : "85251",
    "State" : "AZ",
    "Height" : "6`4",
    "Weight" : "230",
    ....
}
```

The question what is simpler, can only be answered by you yourself, as obviously you implement the App and the Server part. So whatever works best for you is the right way.
Performance-wise, joining strings on one side and splitting them on the other side is not the best, but it also depends on how many entries there are in your array.