# looping through JSONArray but getting nothing

Tags: php

First of all I am a very new to `PHP` so forgive me.

I want to take a `JSON` response and split it up. This will be coming from a `$_POST` variable, however I am trying to test out the would be response in a hard coded variable. The problem is I can't even get it to print in order to see that I'm starting this out right.

```
$json = 
'({
  "array":
  [
    "Store #: 00608",
    "Phone #: null",
    "Address: 3014 N. SCOTTSDALE RD.",
    "City: SCOTTSDALE",
    "Zip: 85251",
    "State: AZ",
    "Height: 6`4",
    "Weight: 230",
    "Ethnicity: White",
    "Age: 23",
    "Eye Color: Blue",
    "Favorite Food: Thai",
    "Comments: awesome"
   ]
})';

$data = json_decode($json,true);
$pieces = explode(":", $data);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['array']); $i++) {
    echo $pieces[$i];
}
```

When I launch this in my browser I get a blank screen, with no errors. End goal is to store these into a `PHP` array as `'Store #', '00608'` etc.

Anyways, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: $data = json_decode($json,true);
echo json_last_error(); // 

prints out error code (if any) from last json-action (encode/decode), you're the lucky winner of code 4 - syntax error :)

Comment: PHP is probably objecting to the use of `array` (it's a keyword). Change that first. Does the data have to be in this format? If you can use `"Store":"00608"` you can extract the data directly as `$json->myArray['store']`

Comment: @MikeW well that would relate to my previous question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197803/creating-json-array-from-arraylist-android/17199135?noredirect=1#17199135). If you have a way for me to do this I am all ears

Comment: @i_me_mine You've already accepted the best answer I have. It's safer than splitting the strings later. If someone enters a `:` in a reply your server-side `explode` will fail. While you're validating this you could just create a JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is pretty much what you're looking for.

```
$json = 
'{
  "array":
  [
    "Store #: 00608",
    "Phone #: null",
    "Address: 3014 N. SCOTTSDALE RD.",
    "City: SCOTTSDALE",
    "Zip: 85251",
    "State: AZ",
    "Height: 6`4",
    "Weight: 230",
    "Ethnicity: White",
    "Age: 23",
    "Eye Color: Blue",
    "Favorite Food: Thai",
    "Comments: awesome"
   ]
}';
$data = json_decode($json,true);

foreach($data['array'] as $piece) {
  $array = explode(': ', $piece);
  echo 'Key: '.$array[0].'<br />';
  echo 'Value: '.$array[1].'<br />';
  echo '<br />';
}
```

Returns

```
Key: Store #
Value: 00608

Key: Phone #
Value: null

Key: Address
Value: 3014 N. SCOTTSDALE RD.
```

Comment: Congratulations you are the lucky winner of a "correct answer". =P. Thanks man, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this JSON.

```
$json = 
'{
  "array":
  [
    "Store #: 00608",
    "Phone #: null",
    "Address: 3014 N. SCOTTSDALE RD.",
    "City: SCOTTSDALE",
    "Zip: 85251",
    "State: AZ",
    "Height: 6`4",
    "Weight: 230",
    "Ethnicity: White",
    "Age: 23",
    "Eye Color: Blue",
    "Favorite Food: Thai",
    "Comments: awesome"
   ]
}';
```

**Notice I took out your ()!**

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid JSON, in that you have parenthesis around the JSON string.  Remove those and it should parse correctly.